# Smallest date from nested json using jquery

Tags: jquery, json

I have a **json** string

```
{
    "name":"experience",
    "spans":[
        {"start":"2013-01-01","end":"2015-12-31","name":"Medical emergency","className":"gap","color":"red"},
        {"start":"2017-03-01","end":"2017-03-16","name":"Test reason","className":"gap","color":"red"},
        {"start":"2010-06-01","end":"2012-20-01","name":"Newtech Media","className":"career","color":"green"},
        {"start":"2016-01-01","end":"2017-03-01","name":"Exlog Technologies","className":"career","color":"green"},
        {"start":"2009-01-01","end":"2009-20-01","name":"Infosys","className":"career","color":"green"}
        ]
}
```

I converted the above **json string** to **json object** using

```
var timeObj = $.parseJSON(data);
```

Now I want the `smallest` **start** `date`. That is from the above string, it is **2009-01-01**.

**How can I get the smallest date from the nested json object?**

I tried a lot but not get the exact. I think someone can help me..

Comment: have you even tried. include what you have tried

Comment: I think **2009-01-01** this is the smallest

Comment: @RanaGhosh, yes I updated..

Comment: @Beginner, I generated the json string dynamically, that is in my question. I stuck at what I was asked...tried a lot but not effective..

Comment: OK I will check each answers..thanks for all..

Comment: *"I converted the above json string to json object using"* - [There's no such thing as a "JSON object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/). The result of parsing the JSON is just an object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
var data = {
    "name":"experience",
    "spans":[
        {"start":"2013-01-01","end":"2015-12-31","name":"Medical emergency","className":"gap","color":"red"},
        {"start":"2017-03-01","end":"2017-03-16","name":"Test reason","className":"gap","color":"red"},
        {"start":"2010-06-01","end":"2012-20-01","name":"Newtech Media","className":"career","color":"green"},
        {"start":"2016-01-01","end":"2017-03-01","name":"Exlog Technologies","className":"career","color":"green"},
        {"start":"2009-01-01","end":"2009-20-01","name":"Infosys","className":"career","color":"green"}
        ]
};

var dateArray = data.spans.map(function(item) {
  return new Date(item.start);
});

dateArray.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a - b;
});

var lowestDate = dateArray[0];
console.log(lowestDate);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

EDITED BELOW IF YOU WANT TO RETAIN IT'S FORMAT

```js
var data = {
    "name":"experience",
    "spans":[
        {"start":"2013-01-01","end":"2015-12-31","name":"Medical emergency","className":"gap","color":"red"},
        {"start":"2017-03-01","end":"2017-03-16","name":"Test reason","className":"gap","color":"red"},
        {"start":"2010-06-01","end":"2012-20-01","name":"Newtech Media","className":"career","color":"green"},
        {"start":"2016-01-01","end":"2017-03-01","name":"Exlog Technologies","className":"career","color":"green"},
        {"start":"2009-01-01","end":"2009-20-01","name":"Infosys","className":"career","color":"green"}
        ]
};

var dateArray = data.spans.map(function(item) {
  return item.start;
});

dateArray.sort(function(a, b) {
  return new Date(a) - new Date(b);
});

var lowestDate = dateArray[0];
console.log(lowestDate);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

not exactly correct format but it should be something like this

```
var smallDate = new DateTime(data.spans[0].start); 
$(data.spans).each(function(){
 var tempDate = new DateTime($this.start);
if(tempDate < smallDate)
{
smallDate =tempDate;
}
})

//smallDate will have th smallet date among the object
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function (e) {
 var string = '{"name":"experience", "spans":[{"start":"2013-01-01","end":"2015-12-31","name":"Medical emergency","className":"gap","color":"red"}, {"start":"2017-03-01","end":"2017-03-16","name":"Test reason","className":"gap","color":"red"}, {"start":"2010-06-01","end":"2012-20-01","name":"Newtech Media","className":"career","color":"green"}, {"start":"2016-01-01","end":"2017-03-01","name":"Exlog Technologies","className":"career","color":"green"}, {"start":"2009-01-01","end":"2009-20-01","name":"Infosys","className":"career","color":"green"}]}';
var timeObj = $.parseJSON(string);
var smallest = new Date(timeObj.spans[0].start);
$.each(timeObj.spans, function(index, value){
 var temp = new Date(value.start);
 if(smallest >  temp)
 {
  smallest = temp;
 }
});
console.log(smallest);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The [array `.reduce()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) is a pretty handy way of finding the smallest/largest/coolest item in an array, because you only need one line of code:

```
smallest = timeObj.spans.reduce(function(a,b) { return a.start < b.start ? a : b }).start
```

Noting that comparing the dates as strings with `<` works with `YYYY-MM-DD` format*, but if they were in some other format you would to need to parse them first.

The only other thing is you need to allow for the case where the array might be empty, so maybe something like this:

```js
var json = `{
    "name":"experience",
    "spans":[
        {"start":"2013-01-01","end":"2015-12-31","name":"Medical emergency","className":"gap","color":"red"},
        {"start":"2017-03-01","end":"2017-03-16","name":"Test reason","className":"gap","color":"red"},
        {"start":"2010-06-01","end":"2012-20-01","name":"Newtech Media","className":"career","color":"green"},
        {"start":"2016-01-01","end":"2017-03-01","name":"Exlog Technologies","className":"career","color":"green"},
        {"start":"2009-01-01","end":"2009-20-01","name":"Infosys","className":"career","color":"green"}
        ]
}`

var timeObj = JSON.parse(json)

// ensure array isn't empty before trying to reduce it
var smallestDate = timeObj.spans.length == 0
                   ? null
                   : timeObj.spans.reduce(function(a,b) {
                       return a.start < b.start ? a : b
                     }).start

console.log(smallestDate)
```

*Although I notice your end dates seem to be a mix of `YYYY-MM-DD` and `YYYY-DD-MM`, so you probably should fix that.